# Información completa de archivos locales en IONIC

Tags: javascript, ionic, ng-cordova

Tengo que listar items formados con la información típica, nombre, ruta, tamaño, fecha modificación etc. El problema es que no se como obtener la información sin tener que extraer los metadatos primero asíncronamente.

```js
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   
   $cordovaFile
     .listDir(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "")
     .then(function(registros) {
        registros.foreach(function(registro) {
          registro.getMetadata(function(metadata) {
            var archivo = {
              nombre: registro.name,
              tamano: metadata.size.
            };
            $scope.listaArchivos.push(archivo);
          });
        });
      });
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Algo así he estado intentando, sin éxito.

Comment: Porque dices "sin éxito"? Te da error? No te dá información suficiente.